# Multi-Threading XNA GameComponents

Tags: multithreading, xna

I am developing an XNA project, where there are two **DrawableGameComponents** *A* and *B*, with the following constraints:

- Either *A* is visible, or *B* is visible. So only one of their "**Draw**" methods has to be called.
- Both *A* and *B* need to be enabled - always. So the "**Update**" method of each has to be called under all circumstances.

Currently both *A* and *B* are executed in the same thread. However, the "Update" methods of them are very CPU-Intensive. Since both GameComponents do not need to talk to each other, and both GameComponents do not need to share any data, it is easily possible to parallelize them.

What I would like to know is how to do that in XNA. The "Update" and "Draw" methods are called by the XNA Framework, so I do not know where to put the Threads. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: multi threading is mildly different on the xbox360 than a PC. it would have to be coded a little differently depending. Is this targeting either one or the other or both? Also, if it is for PC, you have no garrantee that the user has a multi core CPU. If they have a single core CPU, multi threading will probably cost time, not save it.

Comment: the target machine is a PC only. The project is not a game and there will only be one machine with a lot of cores executing it, so there is no problem with multi-threading in general.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done through game state managment, where the `Game1` class (default class) is used to call the `Update()` and/or `Draw()` of other classes (game components)

Take a look at the [xnadevelopment](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml) game state managment tutorial, their they describe how to call diffrent updates and draws of different classes, and hopefully u'll see that multi-threading can be implemented in the Game1 class (default auto-created XNA class)

p.s. if you dont mind doing a lot of reading take a look at this [article](http://www.sgtconker.com/2009/11/article-multi-threading-your-xna/) on XNA multi threading, its accompanied by some diagrams that explain how it works very well.

Comment: Hm, the tutorial only covers game states. In my project, I have two DrawableGameComponents. They have their own Update/Draw. Inside the Game class, I only add those components, like: Components.Add(new MyGameComponentA(this)); And the framework takes care of all the update/draw calls.

Comment: You could pherhaps create two threads in the Game1 Class (the framework takes care of calling Update() and Draw() of Game1.cs), and the thread objects are private, but can be seen in the whole class (class level variables) and each thread runs inside the Update() method, both of them running in parallel.

I hope this explanation is more specific to your situation.

Comment: That would mean they need to be synchronized somehow. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if you need both Update's to run simultaneously so I'm going off the assumption that one component is the only that needs to be drawn.

Using `DrawableGameComponents` they are automatically synced with your `Game` object, but, if you store a reference to each component instead of instantiating them without a stored reference, such as:

```
componentOne = new FirstComponenet(this);
Components.Add(componentOne);
componentTwo = new SecondComponent(this);
Components.Add(componentTwo);
// Immediately disable componetTwo
componentTwo.Enabled = false; // Prevents Update from firing
componentTwo.Visible = false; // Prevents Draw from firing (for Drawable components only)
```

Then you can let XNA manage the Update/Draw loops as per normal. `componentOne` and `componentTwo` being class level variables, you can manage when each are active.

Again, this is based on the assumption that you don't need one to update at the same time the other does.